# What is a difference between tf.GraphDef.FromString and tf.GraphDef.ParseFromString?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

What is a difference between **tf.GraphDef.FromString** and **tf.GraphDef.ParseFromString** ? I cannot find anything for FromString in tensorflow documentaion.

I am trying to run a model protobuf file in C++ but the prediction output is empty. In python example the model is loaded using **tf.GraphDef.FromString** function. In C++ I am using **ReadBinaryProto** method, I am wondering if there is some other way to load the model in C++ that corresponds to **tf.GraphDef.FromString** .

Comment: https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f

Comment: @Deepali I am using that as a reference. But I think the example is very simplistic.  The model only has nodes with no weights.